# Not able to create mysql database using ansible

Tags: mysql, database, ansible, ansible-2.x

> I am writing Ansible playbook to create database in MySQL. I am using
>   Ansible version 2.7. Not able to identify the issue/error. My ansible
>   host system in CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core).
>
> I have PyMySQL installed in my ansible controller machine. MySQL
>   version on traget windows machine is: mysql  Ver 8.0.14 for Win64 on
>   x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL).
>
> ### I have written below ansible playbook code.
>
> - name: Run remote PowerShell script   hosts: win   tasks:
>
>   - name: Create Database in MySQL
>       mysql_db:
>       login_user: user
>       login_password: password
>       name: test
>       state: present
>       register: output
>   - debug: Output="{{ output.stdout }}"
>   - debug: Output="{{ output.stderr }}"
>   - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
>
> My inventory files look like:
>
> [win] some IP
>
> [win:vars] ansible_user=username ansible_password=password
>   ansible_connection= ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
>   ansible_winrm_transport= basic ansible_port= 5985
>
> I am getting below error on running the playbook:
>
> PLAY [Run remote PowerShell script]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************* ok: [18.220.114.161]
>
> TASK [Create Database in MySQL]
>   **************************************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [18.220.114.161]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s):
>   \"At line:4 char:21\r\n+ def _ansiballz_main():\r\n+
>   ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:12 char:27\r\n+ 
>   except (AttributeError, OSError):\r\n+
>   ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:14 char:7\r\n+
>   if scriptdir is not None:\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if
>   statement.\r\nAt line:21 char:7\r\n+     if sys.version_info <
>   (3,):\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt
>   line:21 char:30\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+
>   ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:21 char:25\r\n+     if
>   sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                         ~\r\nThe '<'
>   operator is reserved for future use.\r\nAt line:23 char:32\r\n+
>   MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r\n+
>   ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:23 char:33\r\n+
>   MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r\n+
>
> ```
> statement.\r\nAt line:23 char:32\r\n+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U',
> imp.PY_SOURCE)\r\n+                                ~\r\nMissing
> closing ')' in expression.\r\nAt line:23 char:46\r\n+         MOD_DESC
> = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r\n+                                              ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nNot all parse
> errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try
> again.\"\r\nAt line:6 char:1\r\n+ $exec_wrapper =
> [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r\n+
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    +
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
> MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element
> produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command
> \r\nname, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r\nAt line:7
> char:2\r\n+ &$exec_wrapper\r\n+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo  
> : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    +
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r\n ", "module_stdout": "",
> "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc":
> 1}
>         to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/awx/projects/runbooks/manage_mysql_database/create_mysql_db.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
> ************************************************************************************************************************************************************* IP           : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
> ```

Comment: Hmm... `mysql_db` on windows target?

Comment: yes. My SQL database is on windows target.

Answer (score -1):

try calling AWSCLI command using ansible, which is the solution I exactly faced similar kind of issue while creating MySQL rds through ansible.
Ex:

```
 - name: create rds using cli for decryption
  command: aws rds create-db-instance --db-instance-identifier "{{ StackName }}" --allocated-storage 5 --db-instance-class "{{ db_instance_type }}" --engine mysql --master-username "{{ db_username }}" --master-user-password "{{ db_password }}" --multi-az --storage-encrypted --kms-key-id "{{ kms_id }}" --publicly-accessible --vpc-security-group-ids "{{ SG_Group }}" --db-subnet-group-name "{{ db_subnetgrp }}"
```

Comment: Could you please format your code using triple back-ticks so it is easier to read?

Comment: Thanks Raghu. But I am not using AWS managed database. MySQL is hosted in EC2 Windows instance.